# Fill a HTML5 List with data from Android/Java Code

Tags: android, html, listview

i want to populate a List in an HTML5 File (displayed within a WebView) with data from Android Code (for exmaple from an ArrayList). Can anyone please tell me how or if this is possible.

Thanks in advance
Thommy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a WebView you can simply:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:YOURJAVASCRIPTCODE");
```

Your javascript code could be something like:

```
document.getElementById('txtField1').value = "test";
```

Answer (score 1):

Read this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

You can expose anything from your Android code. If you return some JSON (array or object), you can build your list (or anything else) using some javascript.